# Datatable fnFilter with custom search critaria

Tags: jquery, datatable

I'm using jQuery Datatable v1.9.4, i want to perform custom, or let say range search on datatable, here is screenshot of my datatable.

[image: This is screen cap of my datatable.]

here, in second dropdown, there is a range of days, i want to filter the column `period` based on that, 2<sup>nd</sup> dropdown. for example if `period` has text `01/02/2016 - 29/03/2016` and I'm using filter today on `29/01/2016` and select second option from drop down, `7 days ago` then the row will be filter out.

I'm using this code,

```
jQuery('#period').change(function () {
    selectedValue = jQuery(this).find('option:selected').val();
    jQuery('#dyntable').dataTable().fnFilter(selectedValue, 4, true);
});
```

and of course, it won't work.
can any one help me please.

thanks.

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle for this plz?

Comment: I have created a fiddle on similar lines plz refer it and change your code accordingly https://jsfiddle.net/e7wy1h39/

Comment: @RRR, i had fork your fiddle, but can you please put filter on date range instead of age? i want's like, suppose `Start Date` in your fiddle is between some dates.

Answer (score 0):

ok,

i got the solution.

```
jQuery('#period').change(function () {
    jQuery('#dyntable').dataTable().fnDraw();
});


$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(function (oSettings, aData, iDataIndex) {
    data = aData[4];
    var selectedVal = $('#period').val();
    if (selectedVal != "") {
        selectedSplit = selectedVal.split(" - ");
        dataSplit = data.split(" - ");

        var f = selectedSplit[0].split("/");
        var t = selectedSplit[1].split("/");
        var selectedFrom = new Date(f[2], f[1] - 1, f[0]);
        var selectedTo = new Date(t[2], t[1] - 1, t[0]);

        var f = dataSplit[0].split("/");
        var t = dataSplit[1].split("/");
        var tableFrom = new Date(f[2], f[1] - 1, f[0]);
        var tableTo = new Date(t[2], t[1] - 1, t[0]);

        if (tableFrom.getTime() >= selectedFrom.getTime() && tableTo.getTime() <= selectedTo.getTime()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
});
```

Comment: Isn't the documented way $.fn.dataTable.search.push(...)? Looking here : https://datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/range_filtering.html